# PTY/TTY -Unix: Unable to open Slave FD

Tags: c, terminal, posix, master-slave, pty

I am trying to create a separate PTY terminal. I am trying to achieve using following code.  But Slave FD is always turns out to be -1. Can someone please point me where I am doing wrong.

```
/* Open available PTY */
master_fd = posix_openpt(O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);       
if (master_fd == -1) {
    return -1;
}

/* Give Access to Slave */
if (grantpt(master_fd) == -1) {            
    perror("Unable to Provice Access to Slave");
    goto error;
}

/* Unlock Slave PTY */
if (unlockpt(master_fd) == -1) {
    perror("Unable to lock Slave PTY");
    goto error;
}

/* Get Slave Device Name */
slave_device_name = ptsname(master_fd);                      
if (slave_device_name == NULL) {
    perror("Unable to get Name for Slave Device")
    goto error;
}


slave_fd = open(slave_device_name, O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY);
if (slave_fd == -1) {
    perror("Unable to retrieve FD for slave");
    goto error;
}

error:
close(master_fd);
return -1;
```

Comment: The code looks ok (except for a missing coma after calling `perror` in the `slave_device_name == NULL` check. What's the output of the program?

Comment: @FrederikDeweerdt I am getting slave_fd = -1 all the time. So, it is throwing  "Unable to retrieve FD for slave" error.

Comment: right, but perror outputs the reason for the failure after that message. What does it say?

Comment: It shows as BAD Address

Comment: @FrederikDeweerdt By using ptsname_r, I am able to solve the issue. still not sure why ptsname is not working